# How to find the return type of a function in sybase?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

How to find the return type of a function, for example getdate()? I guess it is a datetime, but how do I know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from looking at the manual, you could do following:

```
select getdate() as d into datatype_debug
go
sp_help datatype_debug
go
```